# Ajuda com campo personalizado

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de colocar em uma  api o meu campo personalizado exemplo:

```
"name"     => "teste", 

"name"     => "<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nome', true ); ?>",
```

abaixo segue o codigo completo:

```
<?php

require('routeros_api.class.php');

$API = new routeros_api();
$API->debug = true;

if ($API->connect('192.168.36.1', 'admin', '987987')) {
   $API->comm("/ip/hotspot/user/add", array(
          "name"     => "teste",
          "password" => "123",   
   ));
   print_r($ARRAY);
   $API->disconnect();
}

?>
```

Comment: Não seria só colocar a variável ali? Sem `echo`

Comment: No caso como que seria sem echo

Comment: `"name" => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nome', true);`

Comment: Nada não deu certo mano